# Name for H2O- radical? (H2O+ radical is Oxoniumyl)

Tags: nomenclature, radicals

Radical are atoms with unpaired electrons, and they have short lifetimes because the unpaired electrons are highly chemically reactive. The $\ce{H2O^{.+}}$ radical is named oxoniumyl. Is there a name for a hypothetical $\ce{H2O^{.-}}$ radical?

Comment: $\ce{H2O^{.-}}$ does not exist.

Comment: That is has not been proven to exist could be one thing (I have not found anything about it being proven to exist, did a quick and very shallow Google search. ) But that it cannot exist, is there theoretical proof for that?

Comment: It might be a very unstable intermediate in some reduction of water reaction.

Comment: There is [gas-phase hydrated radical anion $\ce{(H2O)_n^{.-}}$](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp302076f). I don't know if the anion exist for n=1.

Comment: This question was apparently banned. Nothing about it is out of place. It is a very concise question. I would guess moderation error was the case there.

Comment: @Haverse, what do you mean by that? Your quesion hasn't been closed, nobody has voted to close it, and nobody has even downvoted it.